# Using elementree for flexible processing of HTML data

Tags: python, html, elementtree

I'm using **elementree** to extract data from HTML in a format that has evolved in structure over time (see samples below).

I'm currently doing this by using `iterfind` to find different matching blocks of structure (`font/b`, `b/font`, `font`)

But, I've noticed there is a general pattern.  Regardless of the specific set of HTML elements in use, the ultimate inner text of the first div child is the **color**, the second child is the **pet-type**, and the third child is the **name**.

Is there a generic way of doing this via `elementree`?   That would make my code simpler, and possibly be more future-proof.

```
<div>
  <font><b>Brown</b></font><a>Cat</a><font><b>Larry</b></font>
</div>
<div>
  <b><font>White</font></b><i><a>Poodle</a></i><b><font>Foxy</font></b>
</div>
<div>
  <font><i>Tabby</i></font><a><i>Cat</i></a><font>Tempi</font>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
pets = """<body><div>
  <font><b>Brown</b></font><a>Cat</a><font><b>Larry</b></font>
</div>
<div>
  <b><font>White</font></b><i><a>Poodle</a></i><b><font>Foxy</font></b>
</div>
<div>
  <font><i>Tabby</i></font><a><i>Cat</i></a><font>Tempi</font>
</div></body>"""

animals = []
doc = ET.fromstring(pets)
for pet in doc.findall('.//div'):
    animals.append([animal.text  for animal in pet.findall('.//*') if animal.text]  )

animals
```

Output:

```
[['Brown', 'Cat', 'Larry'],
 ['White', 'Poodle', 'Foxy'],
 ['Tabby', 'Cat', 'Tempi']]
```

Comment: aah, `'.//*'` - that's clever.

Answer (score 0):

This code *appears* to work:

```
        items = div.itertext()
        textblocks = []
        for item in items:
            trimmed = item.strip()
            if len(trimmed) > 0:
                textblocks.append(trimmed)
        color = textblocks[0]
        pet_type = textblocks[1]
        name = textblocks[2]
        print(color + ', ' + pet_type + ', ' + name)
```

I welcome any improvements to the code

Comment: It was a suggested answer.  A better answer has since been provided by +jack-fleeting